# How to build a product list for product ID?

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation

I have about 20 vendor libraries with productID, price, additional fields. I can't combined the document libraries into one because it will get really big (20-30k). All I need is to have productID from all the libraries into a list.

Yes, I know I can create a list and populate it product id from various libraries. But How do I keep this list in sync with libraries.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with an SPD workflow.  Create a new Product ID list, Create a reusable workflow that adds, edits, and deletes the products ID's from this list as they are added, edited, or deleted in the 20 other vendor lists.  Then associate the reusable workflow to each of the vendor libraries.

Comment: Cool. Let me try that option. This mean more work. LOL

Comment: At least you have reusable workflows now. In the old days you would have had to manually create each workflow on each vendor list. Now, you only have to do it once.  You use powershell to create the associations if you want, but unless you are really good at powershell, it would take much more time than just manually creating the 20 workflow associations.